# MATLAB MIRtoolbox - mirtempo function

Tags: matlab

I just want to know how functions like `mirtempo()`, which returns a `mirscalar` object to a direct format that MATLAB can understand.

I have a script which contains

```
tempo = mirtempo('file');
```

this makes `tempo` a `mirscalar` object.

How to convert `tempo` variable to a double value so it could be used in a script?

I need to store the tempo value of multiple songs for song classifications.
I am not able to do that with `mirtempo()`. Rather I can display the tempo value in command window like:

```
tempo
```

Output would be like:

```
"The Tempo related to file classical.00001.au is 165.5543 bpm"
```

Could somebody please help me out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mirgetdata(tempo)

ans = 

120.0106
```

Comment: FYI, you should add a little more explanation with your answer; as it stands the system is flagging it as a "low-quality post" and it may end up getting deleted.

Answer (score 5):

here is the trick:

```
tempo = mirtempo('file');

test=get(tempo,'Data');

test{1,1}{1,1}

ans = 

    [120.0106]
```